# xsl:key match current node from context

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslkey

I have some xml structure like that:

```
<Work>
<Good id ="1">
<outputList>
<outputRow id = "111" pid = "1" pos ="null" desc="List 1"/>
<outputRow id = "112" pid = "111" pos ="null" desc="Category 1"/>
<outputRow id = "113" pid = "112" pos ="1.1" desc="Position 1.1"/>
<outputRow id = "114" pid = "113" pos ="1.1.1" desc="Position 1.1.1"/>
</outputList>
</Good>
<Good id ="2">
<outputList>
<outputRow id = "111" pid = "1" pos ="null" desc="List 1"/>
<outputRow id = "112" pid = "111" pos ="null" desc="Category 1"/>
<outputRow id = "113" pid = "112" pos ="1.1" desc="Position 1.1"/>
<outputRow id = "114" pid = "113" pos ="1.1.1" desc="Position 1.1.1"/>
<outputRow id = "211" pid = "1" pos ="null" desc="List 2"/>
<outputRow id = "212" pid = "211" pos ="null" desc="Category 3"/>
<outputRow id = "213" pid = "212" pos ="3.1" desc="Position 3.1"/>
<outputRow id = "214" pid = "213" pos ="3.1.1" desc="Position 3.1.1"/>
</outputList>
</Good>
<Work>
```

I want output like that:
For each good, for each list in each listOutput for this good I want to see a tree of the list positions.
For the example above I wanna see:

Good (1)
List 1.
 Category 1.
  Position 1.1
   Position 1.1.1

Good (2)
List 1.
 Category 1.
  Position 1.1
   Position 1.1.1

List 2.
 Category 3.
  Position 3.1
   Position 3.1.1

I use xsl:key to get child elements by parentId:

```
<xsl:key name="elementsByPid" match="ns1:outputRow[@pid]" use="@pid" />
```

This key function is using in recursion to create a tree of list categories and positions:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns1:Work/ns1:Good">
      <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="007E1332">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:spacing w:before="40" />
        </w:pPr>
        <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00557C88">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:b-cs />
            <w:i-cs />
            <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>
           <xsl:text>Good (</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>) </xsl:text>
      </w:t>
      </w:r>   
      </w:p> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./ns1:outputList" mode="table" />
  </xsl:template>


   <xsl:template match="/ns1:Work/ns1:Good/ns1:outputList" mode="table">
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="./ns1:outputRow[@pid=1]" mode="row" />
   </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/ns1:Work/ns1:Good/ns1:outputList/ns1:outputRow" mode="row">
    <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="007E1332">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:before="40" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="00557C88">
        <w:rPr>
          <w:b-cs />
          <w:i-cs />
          <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>
          <xsl:text>Пункт:</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="./@pos"/>
          <xsl:text>Описание: </xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="./@desc"/>
        </w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elementsByPid', ./@id)" mode="row"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

The problem is that key match pattern seem to search for @pid in all outputRows, but I need to make it search only in outputRows for current good from context. Is it possible to achieve this anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a key which concatenates the id of the good with the pid of the outputRow:

```
<xsl:key name="elementsByPid" match="ns1:outputRow[@pid]" use="concat(ancestor::ns1:Good/@id, '|', @pid)" />
```

Then use `key('elementsByPid', concat(ancestor::ns1:Good/@id, '|', @pid))`.